# How Can I Open External Url Inside Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I need to open payment method url inside ionic app, but i didn't found any solution of that. I have tried **Iframe** but it doesn't work for payment method urls, because of security reasons i guess. I have also treid **InAppBrowser** that doesn't work.
What I have tried open the url in browser but i need it to open within app.
Any solution?

Comment: These are the two options that I'm aware of. You might need to look into integrating the payment method using their api instead. What is the provider?

Comment: also please be specific, do you want ionic3 or ionic4? they are very different code snippet wise

Comment: @rtpHarry I will integrete KNET, Master and Visa in ionic 4

Comment: It looks like [checkout.com](https://docs.checkout.com/docs/checkoutjs) supports javascript checkout integration of KNET, Mastercard and Visa. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use InAppBrowser-plugin to open an external url.

Install:
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save

npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser
See here:

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit{

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private iab: InAppBrowser) {

    }

    ngOnInit(){

        const browser = this.iab.create('https://www.stackoverflow.com','_self',{location:'no'});

    }

}
```